# Dockerfile Go application build with host cache

Tags: docker, go, continuous-integration

There is a `Dockerfile`

```
FROM golang as builder
RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y
WORKDIR /srv
ADD . /srv
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/go-build \
  go mod download && \
  go generate ./... && \
  go build -o app cmd/main.go
CMD ["/srv/app"]
```

As I understand, `docker build` must not download dependency on each new build and reuse host-binded cache. But it does not.

Can someone suggest, why?

Another idea is to use local go mod cache, but how we can make `docker build` access host network / docker compose bridge network?

Answer (score 0):

You are downloading the dependencies at the same RUN command you are doing `go generate` and `go build`, making all three steps part of the same *layer*. This way, docker can't cache just the dependencies, because it caches by *layer*.

The recommmended way is to separte layers that you want to be able to be cached independently.

```
RUN go mod download
RUN go generate ./...
RUN go build -o app cmd/main.go

etc...
```

Also, you seem to be using a builder pattern, but runing the builder as the final image. This will produce an unnecesary big image (hundreds of MB instead of tens of them). Check [Multi stage builds] https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/) for that matter.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).